# how to update Viewbox in svg-pan-zoom library?

Tags: javascript, svgpanzoom

Im trying to use svg-pan-zoom library, and when zoomin/out and mouse drag mouse x,y position is going wrong, and want to update it but no idea how to do it.
this is how I create svgPanZoom:

```
panZoom(x,y){
   this.panZoomResizer = svgPanZoom('svg',{
      viewportSelector: '.svg-pan-zoom_viewport'
      , panEnabled: true
      , controlIconsEnabled: false
      , zoomEnabled: true
      , dblClickZoomEnabled: false
      , mouseWheelZoomEnabled: true
      , controlIconsEnabled: false
      , preventMouseEventsDefault: true
      , zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.4
      , minZoom: 0.5
      , maxZoom: 10
      , fit: true
      , contain: false
      , center: true
      , eventsListenerElement: document.querySelector('svg .svg-pan-zoom_viewport')
   });
}
```

and want to send value to update viewbox, but dont know how to set it.

```
const distX = (snap.xMouse - this.fp.posX);
const distY = (snap.yMouse - this.fp.posY);
this.panZoom(distX, distY);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code missing here, so better post the entire function/class. 
As a guess you probably want to call `this.panZoomResizer.panZoom(distX, distY);`